# EditText Error Not Working

Tags: java, android-edittext, android

I'm trying to get an EditText error to show up if the text in the EditText is not equal to '1'.  When I enter any text other than '1' no error shows up!  Here is the source code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                if(editText.getText().toString() != "1") {
                    editText.setError("Please enter some information!");
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

The XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

What am I doing wrong?   Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "==" checks if the two objects refer to the same instance of an object.

Answer (score 3):

That's the error :

```
editText.getText().toString() != "1"
```

You need to do :

```
!(editText.getText().toString().equals("1"));
```

Comment: I added the '!' in front of the whole thing

Comment: It's almost like onEditorAction() is not being called.

Comment: Use the log to see what actionId is, because maybe it's not EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT, but EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO, or EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE or something else

Answer (score 2):

String comparison in Java is performed through the methods `String.equals` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase`. `==` and `!=` compares for string's refrence

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the **memory positions** when you use **==** with **strings**.

Please, use the method **equals()** or **equalsIgnoreCase()**.